# How to get parameters from my python scripts and read them from my java project

Tags: java, python

I tried many times to get parameters from my python scripts to my java code.
I used `sys.argv[]` to get parameters from my java code to the python scripts and it is done.
Is there any way to send an argument from python file to an array list on my java code for example.
I need to process these arguments.
I tried this code.

```
public static ArrayList<String> ex(String script) {
    ArrayList<String>a = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] command =
            {
                    "python",
                    script,
            };
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
        //PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(read);
        //stdin.close();
        p.waitFor();
        String s = null;

        while((s=r.readLine())!=null){
            a.add(s);
            System.out.println("s="+s);
        }
        r.close();
        System.out.println("The size = "+a.size());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return a;
}


public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
    istrm_ = istrm;
    ostrm_ = ostrm;
}
public void run() {
    try
    {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
        {
            ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Python...

```
import sys

print("Start\n\n")
sys.stdout.write("Arguments")
```

The process didn't enter the while loop as there is no data returned
the word "Arguments" printed in the console when I run the python script alone or from the java code
But I need it in the array list.